# teradata - invalid select expression list

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Trying to make a select query on teradata, but i get this message error:

> syntax error: invalid select expression list

I can't fix it. How can I formulate the query appropriately?

```
   SELECT BILS01_GRADO, BILS01_CODICE_COM, BILS01_PROT, BILS01_PROG_OGG_IMP,BILS01_PROG_REC,
CASE WHEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP<TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') AND BILS01_CTR_IST_SOSP=0 THEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP
    WHEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP=TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') AND BILS01_CTR_IST_SOSP>0 THEN DATA_CONTROVERSIA2
    WHEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP=TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') AND BILS01_CTR_IST_SOSP=0 THEN TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
    WHEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP<
            (
            CASE WHEN
                (
                CASE    WHEN BILS01_DATA_SPED<to_date('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN BILS01_DATA_SPED
                            WHEN BILS01_DATA_SPED=to_date('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') OR BILS01_DATA_RIC<to_date('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')THEN BILS01_DATA_RIC
                            WHEN  BILS01_DATA_ACQ<to_date('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN BILS01_DATA_ACQ ELSE BILS01_DATA_PROT END AS DATA_CONTROVERSIA
                )
            <TO_DATE('1972-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') THEN TO_DATE('1972-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') ELSE DATA_CONTROVERSIA END AS DATA_CONTROVERSIA2
            )
        THEN BILS01_DATA_PRES_ISTSOSP ELSE DATA_CONTROVERSIA2 END AS A) AS OUT_DATA_RICH_SOSP
FROM zucow.BILS01


--GROUP BY BILS01_GRADO, BILS01_CODICE_COM, BILS01_PROT, BILS01_PROG_OGG_IMP,
--      BILS01_PROG_REC, OUT_DATA_RICH_SOSP
```

Comment: **AS DATA_CONTROVERSIA **

Comment: You probably did some cut&paste and screwed it up. Additionally there's no need for Oracle style `TO_DATE('9999-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')`, use a simple *Standard SQL Date Literal instead*: `DATE '9999-12-31'` (supported by Oracle, too). And GREATEST/LEAST functions exits.

Comment: There are AS clauses in the middle of CASE expressions and also mismatched parentheses.

Comment: The case/when is all mixed up, you've got aliases in the middle of it.  THat can only produce a single column.